# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, request

Getting Missing Schema error even when the links have https: in it

I am trying to **scrape** multiple wiki page using Python, I have a list of wiki URL in an excel.

And created a Python class for scraping the Wiki page and running it through for loop. while running the code without for loop I can get Output, But when I include the following code inside for loop I get the missing schema.

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('list.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

class wiki:

    def __init__(self,url):
        #self.name =name
        self.url = url
        cont = requests.get(self.url, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html.parser")

    def urlcont (self):
        cont = requests.get(self.url, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html.parser")
        print (soup.prettify())
    def head(self):
        cont = requests.get(self.url, timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont.content, "html.parser")
        title = soup.find(class_='firstHeading').i.text 
        return title

for i in range (sheet.nrows):
    url = sheet.cell_value(i,2)
    print (url)

    data = wiki(url)
    head = data.head()
    print (head)
```

Error after running this code

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PYTHON\1click\final\alex.py", line 177, in <module>
    movie = wikimovie(movieurl)
  File "D:\PYTHON\1click\final\alex.py", line 69, in __init__
    cont = requests.get(self.url, timeout=5)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 452, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 313, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 387, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?
```

Output when For loop is removed

```py
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/######

######
```

Output for printing all url (with for loop) without calling the class

```py
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/######
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/######
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/######
```

The output I can get when for loop is ignored and replacing var i with any other random value in this line "url = sheet.cell_value(i,2)"

Comment: Are you sure these are all the URLs in the sheet and that there are no empty lines in the sheet? You might also try `print(repr([sheet.cell_value(i,2) for i in range (sheet.nrows)]))` for debugging.

Comment: Thanks @CristianCiupitu you were there was a empty first row